# Confused about error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Main.main(Main.java:25)

Tags: java

I know questions about this error have been asked before but my situation is different from all the other ones. I am writing code that comes up with the mean, variance, and standard deviation of a data set. I don't get any errors when compiling the code but when I try to run the code I get an error like this : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)

```java
/**   
 * Main class of the Java program. 
 * 
 */

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        double xBar = 0;
        double [] dataSet = {1,2,3,4}; // add data here
        int xLenght = dataSet.length;
        double [] diffrenceSquared={};
        double devSum = 0;
        double variance = 0;
        double standardDeviation = 0;
         for (double n: dataSet)
         {
            sum += n;    
         }
          xBar = sum/xLenght;

          for (int i=0; i<dataSet.length; i++)
          {
            diffrenceSquared[i] = (xBar-dataSet[i])*(xBar-dataSet[i]);
          } 
          for (double n:dataSet)
        {
              devSum += n;
        }    
        variance = devSum/xLenght;

        standardDeviation = java.lang.Math.sqrt(variance);
        System.out.println("x bar ="+xBar);
        System.out.println("variance ="+ variance);
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation ="+ standardDeviation);
    }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Comment: I suggest you to use a List if you want to add items dinamycally otherwise follow the answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `diffrenceSquared` to be a zero-length array with this declaration:

```
double [] diffrenceSquared={};
```

That means that there are no elements to assign, and every index is out of bounds.

You're attempting to assign elements to `diffrenceSquared` in a loop bounded by `dataSet`'s length, so instead declare it to be that length.

```
double[] diffrenceSquared = new double[dataSet.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double [] diffrenceSquared = new double[dataSet.length];
```

In Java, arrays are not resizable, so you have to give them the right size from the start.

Alternatively, you can use `List`s, which are more flexible.

Comment: An explanation of why this is the fix might be helpful :)